# how to set width of gridview in yii2

Tags: php, yii2

how can I set width of column of gridview in view yii2,
reference link as below,

Comment: You can use `contentOptions` in colums array with array of `style`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this,

```
<?=
    GridView::widget([
        'model' => $model,
        'options' => ['style' => 'width:80%'],
        'attributes' => [
            'id',
        ],
    ])
?>
```

Comment: Care to explain how does this answer OP's question? There's a clear asking for setting width / style of a **particular column**. You answer shows how to set options / style for **entire GridView**. That's something totally different.

Answer (score 3):

To set width of one column individually something like the following:

```
[
    'attribute' => 'attribute_name',
    'headerOptions' => ['style' => 'width:20%'],
],
```

For all columns try:

```
[ 
    'class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn', 
    'contentOptions' => ['style' => 'width:100px;'], 
],
```

Comment: this is only for one column, but
i want to apply for all column.